# Origin - subtitles

Tags: translation

In the YouTube original series Origin. Ep 1. 9:15 in the person on the ground says (I think) ...

すわってくださいよ

Which I took to mean “Please sit!” (Or something along those lines).

But the subtitles said “wait - wait a second”

Am I wrong in what I heard? Or did I interpret it incorrectly? Or are the subtitles not exactly a literal translation? Is it a slang?

Link to video https://youtu.be/9fUU6y5-rTc

**Edit**

Listening again and again I think he actually says “ちょっとまってくださいよ” in which case then I agree with the subtitles. :-)

But the first three syllables are almost squashed into a single syllable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, he says ちょっとまってくださいよ and not すわってくださいよ which wouldn't really make sense in the situation they were in.